# Simplest way to add an item between items in a List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

What is the simplest way to add an item between all items in a List?

For example, a List of Strings

`{"1", "2", "3"}`

becomes

`{"1", ",", "2", "," "3"}`

**Edit 1**

My first naive attempt which crashed and burned HARD (don't do this):

```
    for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if(i==0) continue;
        if(i==list.size()) continue;
        list.add(i, new String(","));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'cleanest way'? I think there is only one way to add an new Item to a `List` in Java.

Comment: Have you tried adding the elements you want at the indexes you want them to go? (Hint: it may be easier to add them "back to front," starting at the highest index -- that way, the indexes won't change as you add elements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very *functional* way to think about your problem. Here is what I would do:

```
// use ArrayList, it is very easy to handle and comes with all necessary methods as Payam already said
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");

// this is the actual solution:
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i += 2) {
    list.add(i, ",");
}

// and this is just for testing (printing) the list
for (String s : list) {
    System.out.print("'"+s + "' ");
}
```

Expected outcome would be:

```
'1' ',' '2' ',' '3'
```

So, you loop through your list.
**First:** your index `i` starts at 1 (you don't want to add anything *before* the first element).

**Then** instead of incrementing your index by one (`i++`) you increment it by two (`i+=2`). That way your index points to every *even* position in the list.

**At last** you want to use `add(index, value)` to *add* a new value (here: `,`) to the list at the specified position. Adding a new value to position any position will *shift* the following elements of your list "one to the left". They will not be overwritten (only moved to another index) and you can still loop your list from the beginning to the end, since you don't care if it grows in size or not.

Comment: This is awesome. I appreciate your patience GameDroids.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use an ArrayList it's way easier to add and remove items.

Adding:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = null;
arrlist.add(0, 2);
....
```

Removing:

```
arrlist.remove(index);
```

Comment: Yup, I'm using an ArrayList

Comment: Then just add the items using this add() method. If you want in in a specific position use an index as shown above. If you just need it at the end of your list use a simple arrlist.add(whateverYouwant). For me that's clean enough.

Comment: The idea is to add them between all elements of an unknown length.